# SSRS - Is it possible to sort a chart on a field that is not shown

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a horizontal bar chart with Values, Category Groups, and Series Groups. However I would like to sort on a forth field value that never actually shows in the chart. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have 2008 but in 2012 if you right click on category group and select category group properties a pop up will appear and change sorting options by selecting on sorting from the left hand pane.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a field in 'Category Groups' select the drop down arrow. Then select 'Category Group Properties'. There should be a sorting tab to the left of the resulting window, you should then be able to alter the sort order by changing the data field or inserting a formula.